# Delphi fmx смена курсора при длительных перациях

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

При выполнении длительной операции необходимо изменить курсор на «часики».

В классическом VCL это делалось так:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  OldCursor: TCursor;
begin
  OldCursor := Cursor;
  try
    Cursor := crHourGlass;
    Application.ProcessMessages;
    
    MyProcedure(); // Тут что-то, что выполнятся долго
    
  finally
    Cursor := OldCursor;
  end;
end;
```

В Firemonkey под Windows это не работает — курсор просто не меняется.

Хотя если поставить BreakPoint после смены курсора, то после возобновления выполнения курсор меняется.

Как правильно выполнять смену курсора в Firemonkey внутри процедуры, работающей в основном потоке приложения?

Comment: Application.ProcessMessages - это уже признак плохого проектирования. Что бы оно "лучше" работало, нужно чаще вызывать Application.ProcessMessages

Comment: @KoVadim, так расскажите как делать правильно

Comment: Надо использовать класс TThread (а в делфи уже подвезли новенькое - https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Tutorial:_Using_Tasks_from_the_Parallel_Programming_Library) и вынести "тяжёлую функциональность в отдельный поток.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

как уже и говорили нужен новый поток кроме исключительных ситуаций например долгой загрузки главного окна приложения. там можно доп форму сделать которая создастся в момент создания TForm и при каждой смене контента вызывать `TControl.Update`, а для вашей задачи можно использовать событие по завершению потока

В этом примере я использовал `PostMessage` а что бы пользователь во время выполнения ничего не кликал можно `Enabled := False` поставить только не саму форму а панель которая `Align = alClient`

В моем примере много чего не учтено (например, быстро закрыть программу не дожидаясь окончания) и так так это новый поток и в потоке я трогаю `Self.Handle` который относится к самой форме то может возникнуть исключение типа read write address, поэтому все переменные к которым могут обращаться разные потоки  должны быть продублированы в самом потоке или защищать их критическими секциями.

Как альтернатива `PostMessage` есть событие `TThread.OnTerminate` которое сработает когда поток завершится и сработает оно в том потоке с которого создавали TThread т.е в главном.

```
unit Unit1;
interface
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure MyProcedure;
    procedure MyProcedureFinish(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_USER+1;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Cursor := crSQLWait;
  Panel1.Enabled := False; //чтобы юзер ничего не мог нажать
  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(MyProcedure).Start; // Тут что-то, что выполнятся долго
end;

procedure TForm1.MyProcedureFinish(var Msg: TMessage); //message WM_USER+1;
begin
  Cursor := crDefault;
  Panel1.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.MyProcedure;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
 try
   for I := 0 to 10 do
     Sleep(1000);
 finally
   PostMessage(Self.Handle, WM_USER+1, 0, 0);
 end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Компактнее и удобнее было бы использовать TTask

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Cursor := crSQLWait;
  TTask.Run(
    procedure
    begin
      try
        // Долгая операция
      finally
        TThread.Synchronize(DoneOparation);
      end;
    end);
end;

procedure TForm1.DoneOparation;
begin
  Cursor := crDefault;
end;

Comment: @HemulGM
 не используйте никогда .Synchronize используйте любые другие методы синхронизаций. но через TTask также можно. за долгие часы откладки кода из за непонятных ошибок спасибо тебе Synchronize (из за этого когда то научился бегать под руку с отладчиком)

Comment: твой PostMessage делает точно так же, только не ставит текущий поток на остановку. Он так же генерирует сообщение для ProccessMessages и форма его получает. Synchronize же ставит поток на паузу до завершения синхронизации и выполнения кода внутри. Помимо этого есть Queue и ForceQueue, которые позволяеют управлять очередью при синхронизации и не тормозить поток. Если научиться использовать эти методы ни каких проблем не будет.